# Bringing up interfaces on ceph nodes

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas

I have machines under MAAS with 4 interfaces.  I want to configure my ceph nodes to use two networks that are not the pxe boot network.  MAAS doesn't "up" all of the interfaces when a machine is deployed.  What is the best way to get the interfaces (and associated networks) up before I deploy my ceph services?

Do I do an `juju add-machine --constraints ...` and then do `juju deploy ... ceph --to ...`?

If I just tell MAAS to acquire and start the machine I can manually add the "auto ethx" lines to `/etc/network/interfaces` and then shut them down and release them, but the ceph service is left sitting in an "allocating" state.  The machine is up and I can `juju ssh ceph/0` into it just fine, but there is no `/var/log/juju` directory and it just waits forever.

I understand that the next release of MAAS will bring up all interfaces for me, but what do I do in the meantime to work around it?

Comment: + do you look for a script solution and only for about properties of servers or about properties of display-devices too ?!

Comment: For this bounty, are you looking for a work around?  Because what I described above does work.  Or are you looking for suggestions for what would be nice to see working in the next release with respect to this "feature"?  I have some suggestions for that also.

Comment: The work around that I am using is to:  **juju add-machine
--constraints ...**  This deploys juju client on the machine and
activates juju-br0, then  **juju ssh *machine-number* **   and add
the **auto ethX** lines to **/etc/network/interfaces** and **ifup ethX**
the interfaces.  I can then  **juju deploy ... ceph --to
*machine-number* **  It is not a pretty solution but it does work and
lets me continue with my deployment.

Comment: It would be really nice if a deployment of a machine would not only 
identify juju-br0, but would also bring up each interface and identify 
what network it was on in a similar fashion.  One way to identify the 
networks would be to use the names of the networks as they are define in Networks section of MAAS.